# new drives not listed by lsblk or parted but visible in iDRAC

Tags: server, hard-drive, 22.04, ssd, raid

we have a Dell PowerEdge R7625 server and recently added new Drives 1 SSD and another HDD. The server is installed with Ubuntu 22.04

We already have 10 Disks added configured as RAID 10 and are working well.

The recently added new drives are not showing up when using

1. `lsblk`
2. `parted`

but both the disk are showing up in iDRAC.

Any help here on why Ubuntu does not see the drives would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rescan:

To scan for new disks :

```
echo "- - -" | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan >/dev/null

To rescan existing disks :

echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/block/sd?/device/rescan >/dev/null
```

---

But linux will never see the physical disks if they are in the RAID, the Linux shows only the virtual disks only, which created from the physical disks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTNV21NNvIw